# RPi can write to /media/pi/MyPassport, despite no external media connected

Tags: hard-drive, mount

It's my understanding that the /media/ folder is for mounted/External hard drives.  I have hooked up an external hard drive for storage, and was writing to `/media/pi/My Passport`, no issues.  However, I have removed the USB connection so my Pi isn't connected to anything.

However, I can still use a script to write to /media/pi/My Passport and can view the images in there.

What is the Pi doing? Is it possible I somehow messed up, and just created that folder on the SD Card that holds Raspbian?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/media/pi/My Passport` is just a directory - like any other.

You can use `/media/pi` for any purpose (although generally not a good idea).

The automount utility creates these as needed, but does not necessarily remove them.

EDIT Whenever I use a script to write to an external device I include tests to ensure it is mounted, and in RW mode. One example below:-

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to synchronise Pi files to backup
# 2018-12-17
BACKUP_MOUNTED1=$(mount | awk '/PiData/ {print $6}' | grep "rw")
BACKUP_MOUNTED2=$(mount | awk '/PiHDD/ {print $6}' | grep "rw")
if [ $BACKUP_MOUNTED1 ]; then
    BACKUP_ROOT='/mnt/PiData/'
elif [ $BACKUP_MOUNTED2 ]; then
    BACKUP_ROOT='/mnt/PiHDD/'
fi

if [ $BACKUP_ROOT ]; then
    echo "Commencing Backup"
    if [ $(grep -ic "stretch" /etc/os-release) -gt 0 ]; then
        if [ ! -e /usr/bin/Mathematica ]; then
            BACKUP_DIR="StretchCompactBackup"
        else
            BACKUP_DIR="StretchBackup"
        fi
    elif  [ $(grep -ic "jessie" /etc/os-release) -gt 0 ]; then
        BACKUP_DIR="JessieBackup"
    fi
    BACKUP_ROOT+=$BACKUP_DIR
    echo $BACKUP_ROOT
# Check/create Mount Point
    if [ ! -e $BACKUP_ROOT ]; then
        sudo mkdir $BACKUP_ROOT
    fi
    if [ $BACKUP_ROOT ]; then
    sudo rsync -apH --delete-during --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/usr/bin/rsync-exclude.txt / $BACKUP_ROOT
    fi
else
    echo "Backup drive not available or not writable"
    echo "run sudo mount /mnt/PiData"

fi
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that :D ...now my ultimate question is what happened, I had my `.../MyPassport` being correctly written to the external drive. [Something happened], and suddenly that became `MyPassport1` and then `MyPassport` was created and kept local.  ...but that's a question for another day. This answers it for now, cheers!

Comment: The automount creates directories as needed, but if they exist creates new directories by appending a number. Frankly, I consider this "feature" more of a problem, and have it turned off and manually mount when (and where) I want it.

Comment: Thanks for your edit!  Also, re: automounting - could that be what happened?  Say my Drive is connected, but a power hiccup causes it to disconnect/reconnect. If I had Automounting enabled, could that explain why it renamed my external drive `MyPassport1`?  Because I'm thinking that's what happened, and this could confirm it's technically possible.  Thanks again!!